# Last view added to content view of scrollview goes behind the home indicator

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, scrollview, subview

I have a `UIViewController` containing a *scrollView*.

The *scrollView* is pinned (0,0,0,0) to the `Safe Area`, this way:

[image]
[image]

In the body of the *viewController* `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I add some views to the **Content View** of this *scrollView*.

I see no issue in iPhone 6 simulator, but in iPhone X simulator something strange happens: the last view I add to the scrollview goes partially behind the *home indicator*:

[image]

I erroneously thought this was the kind of issue [solved](https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/how-to-solve-the-most-common-interface-problems-when-adapting-apps-ui-for-iphone-x-44c0f3c80d84) by the `Safe Area`.

What could I do to solve this issue?

Comment: This is the default behavior of safe area guidelines for the recent phone models. I wouldn't change it if I were you.

Comment: @Desdenova: I don't want to change it but how do you deal with it? Should I add a final "spacer" view? Problem is, the current final view could contain vital content that can't "fall" behind that element

Comment: Since you are populating a scroll view manually, you can get the view controller's view, then get `view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` and use that value to inset the scroll view's `contentInset` for its bottom.

Comment: Also if you are targeting above iOS 11, this looks like this will simplify things. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902259-adjustedcontentinset

Comment: @Desdenova: if your first suggestion translated to code is this: `scrollView.contentInset.bottom = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` it works

Comment: @Desdenova: could you provide your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 11 and new iPhone X devices and forward this is the default behavior of [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide).

Scroll view subclasses like table view and collection view handles this problem automatically if you pin the bottom anchor to safe area.

Since you are populating a scroll view manually you need to get the bottom safe area height and inset the scroll view with that value.

You can do it like this:

```
scrollView.contentInset.bottom = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the **ScrollView** BottomConstraint related to superviewBottom instead of safeArea.

Comment: In the simulator, this completely eliminates the home indicator too. I was looking for a solution where the indicator is eventually preserved, the view ends where the indicator begins and any other previous iPhone is ok with safe area. Is it the case for a trait?

Comment: @3000 As of my understanding, you wish to show the views within the safeArea. if this the case then you need to calculate the view height from the wholeScreenHeight only.
viewHeight = (screenHeight - safeAreaHeight) / numberOfViews